# SQL Server Column Store Batch mode giving incorrect result

Tags: batch-processing, columnstore

**Background:** Using SQL Server 2016(SP1) Standard Edition on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard. In one of our production databases, we have a table called tblEMailRequestBodyLines. It contains over 2 million rows, and [sample rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC1KP.png) are shown to give an idea on the general structure of the table (where the first three columns constitute the Clustered Index).

A brief functional info on the table structure – the SessionID represents the logical Email Set, whereas the RequestUniqueID represents the individual emails within that Email Set. InternalRowID is an identity column which defines the order of email body lines, RequestBodyLine. Each Email contains <!-- START OF DETAIL SECTION --> and <!-- END OF DETAIL SECTION --> as bodylines to distinguish the start and end of the details lines of the email content. This table is always queried with SessionID and RequestUniqueID.

**Problem:** We would like to convert current Row Store Clustered Index of the table to Column Store and we did the same in our TEST environment. Post CCI conversion, one of the queries, that finds the InternalROwID of the Start and End of Detail Section is giving incorrect result.  Based on several testing, I am thinking that the discrepancy is due to the way records are processed in Batch-mode of the Column Store Index. I have checked the documentation and several articles on Column Store / Batch mode, but did not get any clue.  Any hint or help to understand the “why” part of the behavior  will be highly appreciated.

**Details:** This is the test case:

```
SELECT  *            
FROM    TEST_ColumnStore_tblEMailRequestBodyLines   
WHERE   fldSessionID            =   '85E55DA4-F2F4-4865-B253-B34F30AA97A9'
AND     fldEMailRequestUniqueID =   '61-20180809-072749.6527584'
AND     fldEMailRequestBodyLine IN 
        (
            '<!-- START OF DETAIL SECTION -->'
            , '<!-- END OF DETAIL SECTION -->'
        )
;
```

Above query produces the result 
[Test Record Rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCVtU.png)

However, the following query,

```
DECLARE @l_StartOfDetail AS BIGINT, @l_EndOfDetail  AS  BIGINT                      

SELECT  @l_StartOfDetail    =   COALESCE(CASE
                                            WHEN fldEMailRequestBodyLine = '<!-- START OF DETAIL SECTION -->' THEN
                                                fldInternalRowID
                                            END, @l_StartOfDetail)
    , @l_EndOfDetail    =   COALESCE(CASE
                                            WHEN fldEMailRequestBodyLine = '<!-- END OF DETAIL SECTION -->' THEN
                                                fldInternalRowID
                                            END, @l_EndOfDetail)                                             
FROM    TEST_ColumnStore_tblEMailRequestBodyLines   
WHERE   fldSessionID            =   '85E55DA4-F2F4-4865-B253-B34F30AA97A9'
AND fldEMailRequestUniqueID =   '61-20180809-072749.6527584'
AND fldEMailRequestBodyLine IN 
                            (
                                '<!-- START OF DETAIL SECTION -->'
                                , '<!-- END OF DETAIL SECTION -->'
                            )
SELECT 'Start of Detail'    =   @l_StartOfDetail, 'End of Detail'   =   @l_EndOfDetail
```

produces the result [with incorrect InternalRowID for End Of Detail section.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fljK.png)

Please note that I used COALESCE, to overcome the possible retrieval of the desired rows in different batches, thus to take final non-null value for the column across all batches.

[Execution plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4bAh.png) shows that the query was executed serially in Batch Mode in [4,877 batches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4moeV.png)

But the same query produces the [correct results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKzLd.png) with the Row Store Clustered Indexed Production table.

I have [a work around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9anH2.png) of creating a temporary table to hold the output rows of Batch execution mode from CCI, and then use the temp table to force the Row execution mode to get the correct result. However I am curious to find out what part of the original query is making the Batch execution mode to produce wrong result.

Again, thank you for reading a really long post and would appreciate any help or hint.